# Satellite/Aerial Imagery for Nepal for mapping in OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, data, aerial-photography, nepal

I was trying to map places in Nepal using satellite imagery but there is no high resolution imagery available at zoom level 15-16 . I was looking to map places like Illam, Dhankuta. Is there a free source of aerial imagery for these places so that i can use it with JOSM to map these places in openstreetmap?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions asking for data are not on-topic on [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

are you in touch with the Nepal community? http://www.osmnepal.org They have quite a lot of projects going on, particularly in the field of Disaster Risk Reduction. Apparently, they have access to higher-resolution images as well: http://tasks.hotosm.org/job/190 (look under the *workflow* tab)

List of curren tasks: http://tasks.hotosm.org/#all/nepal

Comment: Hi, the imagery mentioned on the HOT task is available for Kathmandu region only.

Comment: I am in touch with the core team of the Open Cities Kathmandu Project. The imagery they have access to is only for the capital and the mapping work they have done in Kathmandu is quite impressive. 

But outside the Kathmandu valley Nepal is not much mapped. I was not even able to map a major highway of Nepal "Mechi Highway" due to lack of aerial imagery. Also i wanted to map two major places Illam and Dhankuta but was unable to do so due to same reason. I would love to map these places but i guess i would have to wait until i get a chance to visit these places.

Comment: Well, I think this community is quite invovled in many DRR projects and, as far as I know, works with the World Bank on those. I would thus imagine that getting new images for some critical areas would be possible (not necessarily easy and straight-forward, but still possible.